# What is "ESP_NOW_ROLE_MAX"?

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

While trying out esp-now on a nodemcu v1.0 (esp-12e) I stumbled across `ESP_NOW_ROLE_MAX` while setting the role with `esp_now_set_self_role(...)` and wondered what this could be? Any idea? (I was using Platform.io, but this should also be the same in Arduino IDE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ESP-NOW communication is a communication between peers (master and slave). It is the master device that governs the entire communication initiative and the slaves only respond to the master's request, if applicable.

There is a possibility that a device can simultaneously have the role of master and slave. This happens if the device is the master of one or more slaves and in turn is the slave of another master.

If a device has no role, it will be in idle state.

The table summarizes the four(five) possibilities, with their corresponding names and priority to the interface:

```
esp_now_set_self_role(role) the role can be: 
ESP_NOW_ROLE_IDLE = 0,
ESP_NOW_ROLE_CONTROLLER, 
ESP_NOW_ROLE_SLAVE, 
ESP_NOW_ROLE_COMBO, 
ESP_NOW_ROLE_MAX

Idle –without function-   ESP_NOW_ROLE_IDLE = 0          no interface
Master                    ESP_NOW_ROLE_CONTROLLER = 1    priority is given to the station interface
Slave                     ESP_NOW_ROLE_SLAVE = 2      priority is given to the SoftAP interface
Master + Slave            ESP_NOW_ROLE_MAX = 3       priority is given to the station interface
 Master + Slave           ESP_NOW_ROLE_COMBO         priority is given to the SoftAP interface
```

used like

```
 // Once ESPNow is successfully init, we will register for Send CB to
  // get the status of Trasnmitted packet
  esp_now_set_self_role(ESP_NOW_ROLE_CONTROLLER);
  esp_now_register_send_cb(OnDataSent);

  // Register peer
  esp_now_add_peer(broadcastAddress, ESP_NOW_ROLE_SLAVE, 1, NULL, 0);
```

To read more details about the [possible scenarios look here](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp-now-esp32-arduino-ide/)

 More info in the [sources](https://github.com/HarringayMakerSpace/ESP-Now).